# Execution of worker after user saved Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, sidekiq

I have one problem, i try exec a Sidekiq worker after Devise saved the user, but not work. If i dont use the function of test, works fine. But i dont need when user enter in this page, i need when user complete the register.

I find how do this, but dont work fine.
Example:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :get_ml_informations, :only => :new
...
def after_sign_up_path_for(users)
    # @product_list = get_products(@token)
    # SignupWorker.perform_async(@product_list, @token)
end
...
end
```

**Error**: `undefined method "user_url" for #<RegistrationsController:0x007f8bf6bf1f38>`

Or, this too:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # @product_list = get_products(@token)
    # SignupWorker.perform_async(@product_list, @token)
  end
```

**Error**: Show any error in my view, i dont understand...

I have too custom fields in Devise, but, works fine:

```
def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :first_name, :last_name)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using:

```
def create  
    super  
    if @user.save  
     ...  
    end

end
```

Comment: You can also use observer for the same